# What does "on a Hot Streak" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used these links but they have different meanings, so I was not sure what "on a Hot Streak" means

Urban Dictionary: [hot streak](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hot%20Streak)

Oxford Dictionaries: [hot streak](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hot_streak)

M-W: [hot streak](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hot%20streak)

Here are some sentences from the article:
"Japan’s Economy Is Growing, but Don’t Call It a **Hot Streak**"

"Is the Economy **on a Hot Streak**?"

https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/17/business/japan-gdp.html?ref=business

Comment: Oxford and Merriam Webster give the same definition, and this is what is meant in the NYT article. The Urban dictionary is a **slang** dictionary, it does not give mainstream definitions. I doubt a NYT business article would use a word according to a definition found in the Urban dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

A hot streak is a length of time where everything is going right.  A good example is a salesman.  If he has made a sale to every person he spoke to that week, he could be said to be on "a hot streak."

Alternatively, it is used very often in sports.  If the New York Yankees have won several difficult games in a row they can be said to be "on a hot streak."

In terms of economy, a hot streak would normally mean certain numbers are doing well over a set period of time.  I.E. GDP has gone up several years in a row, unemployment has dropped for 6 consecutive months, the stock market has hit record highs 3 months in a row, etc.